# What's wrong with my way of constructing an object of a subclass?

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, mfc

Here's my subclass:

```
class BackGround :public Object{
public:
BackGround(int y){
    character.Load(_T("wallpaper.png"));
    x = 0;
    this->y = y;
    direct = 0;
    width = 1200;
    height = 375;
}
};
```

my base class:

```
class Object{
public:
CImage character;     
int x;             
int y;
int direct;       
int speed;
int width;      
int height;
int Xcenter;
int Ycenter;

Object(){}

void draw(HDC hDC){
    character.Draw(hDC, x, y, width, height, 0, direct*height,width, height);
}
};
```

When I create objects of the class BackGround,
       `BackGround Bg1(0);
    BackGround Bg2(-WINDOW_HEIGHT);`

There come errors：

```
1>  MainFrm.cpp
1>c:\users\desktop\mfcgame\mfcgame\childview.h(46): error C2059: syntax error: 'const'
1>c:\users\desktop\mfcgame\mfcgame\childview.h(47): error C2059: syntax error:“-”
1>  MFCGame.cpp
1>c:\users\desktop\mfcgame\mfcgame\childview.h(46): error C2059: syntax error: 'const'
1>c:\users\desktop\mfcgame\mfcgame\childview.h(47): error C2059: syntax error:“-”
1>  ChildView.cpp
1>c:\users\desktop\mfcgame\mfcgame\childview.h(46): error C2059: syntax error: 'const'
1>c:\users\desktop\mfcgame\mfcgame\childview.h(47): error C2059: syntax error:“-”
1>c:\users\desktop\mfcgame\mfcgame\childview.cpp(67): error C2228: left of '.draw' must have class/struct/union type
1>c:\users\desktop\mfcgame\mfcgame\childview.cpp(68): error C2228: left of '.draw' must have class/struct/union type
1>c:\users\desktop\mfcgame\mfcgame\childview.cpp(116): error C2228: left of '.y' must have class/struct/union type
1>c:\users\desktop\mfcgame\mfcgame\childview.cpp(118): error C2228: left of '.y' must have class/struct/union type
1>c:\users\desktop\mfcgame\mfcgame\childview.cpp(120): error C2228: left of '.y' must have class/struct/union type
1>c:\users\desktop\mfcgame\mfcgame\childview.cpp(122): error C2228: left of '.y' must have class/struct/union type
```

Comment: "There come errors" isn't very useful information. Please post the exact errors. (Use copy and paste.)

Comment: Copy the messages from the Output window and not from the Error List window. (There's usually more and better information there.) Also, what is the definition of `WINDOW_HEIGHT`?

Comment: WINDOW_HEIGHT is a macro.`#define WINDOW_HEIGHT 1400`

Comment: the errors indicate `BackGround Bg1(0);
    BackGround Bg2(-WINDOW_HEIGHT);`

Comment: Where is the childview code?

Comment: it's a class `class CChildView : public CWnd`  which contains `BackGround Bg1(0); BackGround Bg2(-WINDOW_HEIGHT); `

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have

```
class CChildView : public CWnd
{
    // ...
    BackGround Bg1(0);                // Line 46
    BackGround Bg2(-WINDOW_HEIGHT);   // Line 47
};
```

and that's incorrect syntax for declaring member variables.
(The compiler thinks these look like declarations of member functions.)

If you're using C++11, you can write

```
class CChildView : public CWnd
{
    // ...
    BackGround Bg1 {0}; 
    BackGround Bg2 {-WINDOW_HEIGHT};
};
```

with curly braces, or you can initialise the members in the constructor's initialiser list, which works in all C++ versions:

```
class CChildView : public CWnd
{
    CChildView();
    // ...
    BackGround Bg1; 
    BackGround Bg2;
};

// ... 

CChildView::CChildView() : Bg1(0), Bg2(-WINDOW_HEIGHT)
{
    // ...
}
```